# In Python shall I test installed version of code or the uninstalled version

Tags: python

Shall I test an installed version of my code as recommended in https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html ?

Or shall I test the uninstalled version as recommended in http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#structure-of-the-repository ?

What is the best practice here?

Comment: I wonder if this question is better suited for [SoftwareEngineering.se].

Comment: How do you test uninstalled code?

Comment: @cricket_007 - the first link explains how `pytest` adds paths to `sys.path` which could cause you to accidentally import a package in your repository when you really intended the installed version. Generally, you always have the choice to just add the directory where your source package resides to PYTHONPATH and you'd be running an uninstalled version of the code. Harmless for packages where the repo matches installation but a problem when there are things like C extension builds.